# Can anyone help me to redirect to the selected country in this autocomplete form on submit?

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, autofill

Can anyone help me in the right direction? I am still quite new to coding.
I found this script on W3 school that I would like to adjust to my needs a little.

On submit I want to be redirected to : www.url.com/?mycountry=selectedcountry.

Is this possible and how to get there? Thanks a lot Martin

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `method="GET"` to your `<form>` here is the example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

That will help you to do the thing

Comment: Thanks Krunal, that works indeed. 
Now are the values in an included var that is quite limiting. Would it be possible to get these via api from an external file you think or any other suggestions to stack several 1000 values?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry Krunal, I will try to explain. At this moment the countries are completed from the var/list in the script. var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina.
That is "okay" for 300 countries.
But I have a CSV with 7000 city names. So adding all these values to the script is probably not best solution.
Would it be possible to GET the values?

Comment: For that you must need to take help of PHP code and you must need 2 dropdown one for Country and another for City so when user submit form it will have 2 values one is for country and another is for City which they will choose from dopdown will go into GET values, I hope this make sense

Comment: don't need a second value. Only the value city instead of country. But look for other "source" then the var[list] to store the 7000 city names, thank  you!

Comment: What you can do is just make dropdown via php code fetch values from file and list them directly in dropdown, hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks Krunal, sounds exactly want I need, will try to investigate and figure this next step out, because this is quite new to me

Comment: Yes sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

The method attribute specifies how to send ***form-data*** (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).

The form-data can be sent as URL variables `(with method="get")` or as ***HTTP post transaction*** `(with method="post")`.

**Notes on GET:**

- Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs
- The length of a URL is limited (about 3000 characters)
- Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)
- Useful for form submissions where a user wants to bookmark the result
- GET is better for non-secure data, like query strings in Google

**Notes on POST:**

- Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not
  shown in URL)
- Has no size limitations
- Form submissions with POST cannot be bookmarked

Comment: Thanks Navnish, didn't know this length of an url and indeed made it work with GET method